# Selenium - follow fast loading indicator

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

I need to test a data table, which on every change has a loading indicator.
Sometimes this indicator is very fast.
Is there any best practice for selenium in order to follow these very fast UI changes? (Such as loading indicator).

Comment: What type of indicator? Is it an image or something else?

Comment: It is just a div

Comment: I'm trying to understand. An example: very often, indicators are an image that changes depending on the loading progress. So you would have image that changes it's source attribute from e.g. "loading25percent.png" to "loading50percent.png"... Can you share some HTML around that div?

Comment: I'm not able to share since it's a production code. The thing is when loading there is a div with loading text. I want to ve able to watch whether it is visible or not.

Comment: Have you tried something like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div")).isDisplayed()`?

Comment: But what happens if the loading is too fast, and it will fail to find it? How can I verify the loading showed up?

Comment: If you are watching the same element before and after an event (a click, let us say), you should get a `Stale Element Reference Exception` if the interaction with the web page is too fast for the web driver to get it. Maybe you could use that?

Comment: But how can I know that it showed up from the beginning, and the reason I get the exception is that it was too fast, or it was not showing up from the beginning?

Comment: If the element was never present you should get `No Such Element Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following c# to query the dom for id's and classes with known loading values and wait for them to not be present. Using driver.FindElement(By*) attempts to declare the element is present at a given identifier rather than searching for it, which will cause errors and isn't the behavior we're looking for.

```
public IWebDriver WaitForPage()
    {// Query document for loading elements until none found
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,MyDefaultTimeout)
        .Until( 
            e => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)e) 
                .ExecuteScript(@"
                    var MyDefaultTimeout = 500; 
                    var loaded = false;
                    do {
                        var elementClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('//*[contains(@class=\'is-loading\') or contains(@class=\'fa-gear\') or contains(@class=\'loading\') and not(@class=\'displayed\')]');
                        var elementIds = document.getElementById('//*[contains(@id=\'hover-gear\') or contains(@id=\loading-gear\')]');
                        if((!elementClasses === null) || (!elementIds === null)){
                            setTimeout(function() { loaded = false }, MyDefaultTimeout);
                            }
                        else{ 
                            if(!document.readyState === 'complete'){
                                setTimeout(function() { loaded = false }, MyDefaultTimeout);
                                }
                            else{ 
                                loaded = true;
                                return document.readyState;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    while(loaded === false);", null))
                .Equals("complete");
        return driver;
    }
```